# Alternate optimization with two different optimizers in pytorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch, gradient-descent

- I have two loss functions `l1` and `l2`, each optimized by two separate ADAM optimizers `opt1` and `opt2`.
- The current value of my parameters is `x`.
- I want to update `x` using `opt1` and `opt2` separately, and then "merge" the resulting new value of `x` depending on the magnitude of the gradients.

Pseudocode

```
grad1 = get_grad(l1)
grad2 = get_grad(l2)
n1 = norm(grad1)
n2 = norm(grad2)
x1 = opt1(grad1)
x2 = opt2(grad2)
w = n1 / (n1 + n2)
x = w*x1 + (1-w)*x2
```

How can I do it in pytorch? I am not sure how to use `backward()` and `step()`.

Comment: my best guess is you will have to maintain two different models, do the optimization steps seperately and then update parameters of each model in merging the step

Answer (score 0):

Following @UmangGupta comment, I did it by initializing three copies of `x`: two for `x1` and `x2`, and one for a backup of `x`. Then I do as follows

```py
def copy(target, source):
    for x, y in zip(target.parameters(), source.parameters()):
        x.data.copy_(y.data)

def merge(target, source1, source2, tau):
    for x, y1, y2 in zip(target.parameters(), source1.parameters(), source2.parameters()):
        x.data.copy_(tau * y1.data + (1.0 - tau) * y2.data)

def grad_norm(x)
    n = 0.
    for p in x.parameters():
        p_norm = p.grad.data.norm(2)
        n += p_norm.item() ** 2
    return n ** (1. / 2)

...

copy(x_backup, x)

opt1.zero_grad()
l1.backward()
n1 = grad_norm(x)
opt1.step()
copy(x1, x)
copy(x, x_backup)

# same for opt2, x2, n2

merge(x, x1, x2, n1 / (n1 + n2))
```

I'd still like to have a cleaner way, if possible (not sure if copying the value, which happens very often, makes my code slower).